# 403 forbidden in MVC application when trying to browse directory without controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

I have a directory in my project which is "~//Api"

It has no controller associated with it.

It's purpose is to serve .json files, to be accessed by an external service.

I am concerned that when I go to configure this external service, it will not be able to see a complete file listing; When I browse the directory http://example.com/Api/ I get a 403 forbidden error.

My external service (icinga) will need full access to my Api directory to constantly monitor all .json files in the directory which change and can be added, so specifying a list of files to check will not suffice.

However if I do http://example.com/Api/88888.json I see my file exactly as I should.

Is there no native functionality to display the contents of a directory as a file listing? Or is there a security setting somewhere on the server that is preventing a directory's contents from being listed? (I'm the server administrator running IIS 8.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable directory browse using your web.config

```
   <configuration>
     <location path="Api">
         <system.webServer>
              <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
         </system.webServer>
    </location>
   </configuration>
```